How to passthrough USB in Android Studio emulator
I really, really would like to use and test my USB device through the emulator on android studio, and not have to resort to pluging it into a physical device.
There has to be a way to do this, I just can't seem to find it. All I can find is a article for Android Automotive OS, https://source.android.com/docs/automotive/start/passthrough. But this does not seem to work. After running the emulator, I just get this, it's like nothing happened, and my app does not detect the USB device.
luispl@luispl:\~/Android/Sdk/emulator$ ./emulator @Nexus_4_API_33 -no-snapshot -qemu -device usb-ehci,id=ehci -device usb-host,bus=ehci.0,vendorid=0x0483,productid=0x5740
INFO    | Android emulator version 32.1.12.0 (build_id 9751036) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath /home/luispl/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-33/google_apis/x86_64/
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-luispl/emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
WARNING | cannot add library /home/luispl/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
INFO    | added library /home/luispl/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
INFO    | Sending adb public key \[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 luispl@unknown\]
WARNING | \*\*\* No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.\*\*\*
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: none
INFO    | Advertising in: /run/user/1000/avd/running/pid_188088.ini
INFO    | Setting display: 0 configuration to: 768x1280, dpi: 320x320
INFO    | Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:

My app filters for the right pid and vid USB device, and upon connecting the USB device, it is supposed to show "Choose app for USB device", but on the emulator, nothing.
I also tried passing the port instead of the device.
This seems to be doing something now, but still some issues:
 luispl@luispl:~/Desktop$ sudo ./run_emulator.sh -avd Nexus_4_API_33 -no-snapshot -qemu -device usb-ehci,id=ehci -device usb-host,bus=ehci.0,hostbus=1,hostport=7 INFO    | Android emulator version 32.1.12.0 (build_id 9751036) (CL:N/A) INFO    | Found systemPath /home/luispl/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-33/google_apis/x86_64/ INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-luispl/emu-crash.db, detection is enabled INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. WARNING | cannot add library /home/luispl/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed INFO    | added library /home/luispl/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so INFO    | Sending adb public key [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 root@unknown] Home directory not accessible: Permission denied pulseaudio: pa_context_connect() failed pulseaudio: Reason: Connection refused pulseaudio: Failed to initialize PA contextCould not init `pa' audio driver
WARNING | \*\*\* No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.\*\*\*
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: none
WARNING | Using fallback path for the emulator registration directory.
INFO    | Advertising in: /home/luispl/Android/Sdk/avd/running/pid_199112.ini
WARNING | Using fallback path for the emulator registration directory.
INFO    | Setting display: 0 configuration to: 768x1280, dpi: 320x320
qemu-system-x86_64: Warning: speed mismatch trying to attach usb device "STM32  BOOTLOADER" (full speed) to bus "ehci.0", port "1" (high speed)
qemu-system-x86_64: Warning: speed mismatch trying to attach usb device "STM32  BOOTLOADER" (full speed) to bus "ehci.0", port "1" (high speed)
qemu-system-x86_64: Warning: speed mismatch trying to attach usb device "STM32  BOOTLOADER" (full speed) to bus "ehci.0", port "1" (high speed)
INFO    | Boot completed in 30070 ms
INFO    | Increasing screen off timeout, logcat buffer size to 2M.
INFO    | Revoking microphone permissions for Google App.

This log now shows "Warning: speed mismatch".
What is more strange is that it seems to be picking up on the device, yet no Intents are lauched. Take a look at the logcat, when I plug in the device:
08-06 22:20:32.904     0     0 I usb 1-1 : new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
 08-06 22:20:33.085     0     0 I usb 1-1 : New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=5740, bcdDevice= 2.00 
08-06 22:20:33.087     0     0 I usb 1-1 : New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3 
08-06 22:20:33.101     0     0 I cdc_acm 1-1: 1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device

This is my device. So why does my app not pick up on anything? Why does the USB intent not get lauched?
